# Can't find service: ALTextToSpeech - Trying to run Pepper simulator on Choregraphe

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper

I'm trying to connect to the virtual robot on Choregraphe.
The virtual robot is running on Port 58386 on my computer.
This is the code:

```
from naoqi import ALProxy
tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", "127.0.0.1", 58386)
tts.say("Hello, world!")
```

This is the error thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", "127.0.0.1", 58386)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\naoqi.py", line 344, in __init__
    inaoqi.proxy.__init__(self, args[0], args[1], args[2])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\inaoqi.py", line 318, in __init__
    this = _inaoqi.new_proxy(*args)
RuntimeError:   ALProxy::ALProxy
    Can't find service: ALTextToSpeech
```

I've tried looking for this error, but couldn't find the solution anywhere. What am I doing wrong here? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to import any other modules? Like `ALMemory` for example?

Comment: @DominicD I tried importing other modules. None of the modules seems to work. Throws the same error: ```Can't find service: ```

Comment: There's no TextToSpeech nor Automatic Speech to Text in the simulator.

Comment: @AlexandreMazel Thank you, but is there any specific reason why other modules don't work either?

Comment: standard modules not relative to hardware should work, try for instance ALMemory

Comment: @AlexandreMazel, thank you. I found this old link [link](https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/ja/node/1117) and I'm trying to do the exact same thing where I keep Choregraphe open and I'm trying to connect to the virtual robot through an outside shell. When I try to run ALMemory, I get the same error `RuntimeError: ALProxy::ALProxy Can't find service: ALMemory`

Answer (score 0):

Speech synthesis on virtual robots is not supported.
You can still simulate dialogues using `ALDialog` API.
Choregraphe can show the output in its dialog widget, and let you input text too.

Comment: Victor Paléologue, Thank you.